# Unity configure 2 implementation for one interface

Tags: c#, unity-container

Hi I am using unity as my ioc container and I have a case where I need to use an implementation for a specific case and for the rest of the case another implementation.

This is my interface:

```
public interface IMappingService<TFrom , TTo>
{
    TTo Map(TFrom source);
}
```

And this are my two implementations:

```
 public class AutoMapperService<TFrom, TTo> : IMappingService<TFrom, TTo>
{
    public TTo Map(TFrom source)
    {
        TTo target = Mapper.Map<TTo>(source);
        this.AfterMap(source, target);
        return target;
    }

    protected virtual void AfterMap(TFrom source, TTo target)
    {

    }
}

public class AutoMapperGetUpcomingLessonsService : AutoMapperService<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>
    {
        private readonly IOfficialNamesFormatter m_OfficialNamesFormatter;

        public AutoMapperGetUpcomingLessonsService(IOfficialNamesFormatter officialNamesFormatter)
        {
            m_OfficialNamesFormatter = officialNamesFormatter;
        }

        protected override void AfterMap(GetUpcomingLessons_Result source, UpcomingLessonDTO target)
        {
            target.TeacherOfficialName = m_OfficialNamesFormatter.GetOfficialName(target.TeacherGender,
                                                                                  target.TeacherMiddleName,
                                                                                  target.TeacherLastName);
        }
    }
```

I acces the implementations in my code using IServiceLocator:

```
ServiceLocator.GetInstance<IMappingService<IEnumerable<GetUpcomingLessons_Result>, IEnumerable<UpcomingLessonDTO>>>();
```

In most of the case I would like to use the AutoMapperService implementation and for doing this I specified this in my dependencyConfig file:

```
  container.RegisterType(typeof(IMappingService<,>), typeof(AutoMapperService<,>));
```

The problem appears when I want to use AutoMapperGetUpcomingLessonsService as my implementation.I tried adding this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMappingService<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>, AutoMapperGetUpcomingLessonsService>();
```

But it seems the code is not reached.How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is defined as:

```
AutoMapperGetUpcomingLessonsService 
    : AutoMapperService<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, UpcomingLessonDTO>
```

And registered like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMappingService<GetUpcomingLessons_Result, 
    UpcomingLessonDTO>, AutoMapperGetUpcomingLessonsService>();
```

But is resolved like this:

```
ServiceLocator.GetInstance<IMappingService<
    IEnumerable<GetUpcomingLessons_Result>, IEnumerable<UpcomingLessonDTO>>>();
```

Since you are registering closed generics the types need to match exactly.  `IEnumerable<GetUpcomingLessons_Result>` is not the same type as `GetUpcomingLessons_Result`.  So you should either resolve without the `IEnumerable` or change the class definition and registration to be `IEnumerable<T>`.